# Advertisement error - HTML error visible to user

Tags: bug, advertising

Sometimes I see this error on this site.

```
 width=0 height=0 style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;'>
```

[image]

Comment: chrome browser.. i'm using OS maverick